# Adjusting height of Mapbox fill-extrusion in React js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Good day!

I have a Mapbox map with an extruded polygon layer. I receive the data from a database and then display the geoJSON output using an extruded polygon. What I want to do is to increase the height of the polygon in the front-end, without having to change the data in the geoJSON.

So basically I want to do something like this:

`"fill-extrusion-height": ["get", "hh_density_2042"]` * 20

If that makes sense. I just want to use the values from the geoJSON, but I want to increase the height on the map. How do I do this?

PS. I have tried interpolation, but I don't want to bin the data.

All assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to express the multiplication with a Mapbox GL expression:

```
"fill-extrusion-height": ["*", ["get", "hh_density_2042"], 20]
```